# How to get the list of all printers in computer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to get the list of all printers that connect to computer?

How I can do it in C#, WinForms?

Answer (score 248, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (string printer in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
    MessageBox.Show(printer);
}
```

Comment: Never thought of searching for this in System.Drawing!

Answer (score 69):

If you need more information than just the name of the printer you can use the `System.Management` API to query them:

```
var printerQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * from Win32_Printer");
foreach (var printer in printerQuery.Get())
{
    var name = printer.GetPropertyValue("Name");
    var status = printer.GetPropertyValue("Status");
    var isDefault = printer.GetPropertyValue("Default");
    var isNetworkPrinter = printer.GetPropertyValue("Network");

    Console.WriteLine("{0} (Status: {1}, Default: {2}, Network: {3}", 
                name, status, isDefault, isNetworkPrinter);
}
```

Answer (score 27):

Look at the static [System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters.aspx) property.

It is a list of the names of all installed printers on the system.

Answer (score 9):

**Get Network and Local Printer List in ASP.NET**

This method uses the Windows Management Instrumentation or the WMI interface. It’s a technology used to get information about various systems (hardware) running on a Windows Operating System.

```
private void GetAllPrinterList()
        {
            ManagementScope objScope = new ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath); //For the local Access
            objScope.Connect();

            SelectQuery selectQuery = new SelectQuery();
            selectQuery.QueryString = "Select * from win32_Printer";
            ManagementObjectSearcher MOS = new ManagementObjectSearcher(objScope, selectQuery);
            ManagementObjectCollection MOC = MOS.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in MOC)
            {
                lstPrinterList.Items.Add(mo["Name"].ToString());
            }
        }
```

[Click here to download source and application demo](http://www.codescratcher.com/windows-forms/get-network-and-local-printer-list-in-asp-net/)

Demo of application which listed network and local printer

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the `LocalPrintServer` class. See: [System.Printing.LocalPrintServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.localprintserver?view=netframework-4.8)

```
public List<string>  InstalledPrinters
{
  get
  {
     return (from PrintQueue printer in new LocalPrintServer().GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local,
             EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections }).ToList()
             select printer.Name).ToList(); 
  } 
}
```

As stated in the docs: **Classes within the `System.Printing` namespace are not supported for use within a Windows service or ASP.NET application or service.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with MVC C#, this is the way to deal with printers and serial ports for dropdowns.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

    public class Miclass
    {
        private void AllViews()
        {
            List<PortClass> ports = new List<PortClass>();
            List<Printersclass> Printersfor = new List<Printersclass>();
            string[] portnames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            /*PORTS*/
            for (int i = 0; i < portnames.Count(); i++)
            {
                ports.Add(new PortClass() { Name = portnames[i].Trim(), Desc = portnames[i].Trim() });
            }
            /*PRINTER*/
            for (int i = 0; i < PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count; i++)
            {
                Printersfor.Add(new Printersclass() { Name = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i].Trim(), Desc = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i].Trim() });
            }
        }
    }
    public class PortClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} ({1})", Name, Desc);
        }
    }
    public class Printersclass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} ({1})", Name, Desc);
        }
    }
```