# How to list all printers on network computer

Tags: c#, powershell, printing, wmi

As shown below in the picture, when I tried to retrieve all printers, I got only 2 printers.

Is there a way to return all printers using either PowerShell WMI or C#(so that I can translate it in powershell)?

I have tried `System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters` (refer to [`how to get the list of all printers in computer - C# Winform`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354435/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-printers-in-computer-c-sharp-winform)) but also displays only 2 entries.

[image]

Comment: There is something that is not clear in your question (the doubt arises from the command prompt screenshoot). Are you trying to find the installed printers on a network computer thar is not your own?

Comment: Yes you are right, Steve.  I am trying to get printers on a network computer and not on my own

Comment: Just tried your PS script now on my network and I can get all the printers on a network server. Could just be a permission problem? Here I am an administrator and have the full permission to printers on that server-

Comment: @Steve: I am trying to figure out if it's a permission issue. I will get back to you soon

Answer (score 3):

Simply,

via [System.Drawing.Printing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.aspx)

```
foreach (String printer in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
    Console.WriteLine(printer.ToString()+Environment.NewLine);
}
```

via [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

```
public static void AvailablePrinters()
{
 oManagementScope = new ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);
 oManagementScope.Connect();

 SelectQuery oSelectQuery = new SelectQuery();
 oSelectQuery.QueryString = @"SELECT Name FROM Win32_Printer";

 ManagementObjectSearcher oObjectSearcher = 
    new ManagementObjectSearcher(oManagementScope, @oSelectQuery);
 ManagementObjectCollection oObjectCollection = oObjectSearcher.Get();

 foreach (ManagementObject oItem in oObjectCollection)
 {

 Console.WriteLine("Name : " + oItem["Name"].ToString()+ Environment.NewLine);
 }
}
```

via [PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd835506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
Get-WMIObject -class Win32_Printer -computer $printserver | Select Name,DriverName,PortName
```

---

For more information, please check this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80680/Managing-Printers-Programatically-using-C-and-WMI) & WMI Printer [Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific in the question that, I am trying to retrieve printers installed on a remote machine.  Say if my computer name is comp1, then I'd like to list printers on a machine named comp2, not the list of printers installed on comp1

Comment: are you get the solution now i have a same problem "Say if my computer name is comp1, then I'd like to list printers on a machine named comp2, not the list of printers installed on comp1"