# Check printer if connected to pc or not

Tags: c#

I need to write some code that would prompt a message "printer is connected" when the printer is plugged into the computer and also prompt a message "printer not connected" when I plug out the printer from computer. I also want to list the printers available through a `combobox`. How can I do this in C# using Visual Studio?

Comment: plugged in/plugged out seems okay.. but what you mean by combo box ?? when u want it?? at the time or print? then let me tell u windows by default `Ctrl+P` is there to list printer and select one.. for plugging in/out we can try..!

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354435/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-printers-in-computer-c-sharp-winform

Comment: i want to put the list of the printers installed to a combobox sir. im still noob at c# sorry if you dont understand some of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Winspool.lib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162751(v=vs.85).aspx)

C# Signature :

```
[DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);
```

**EDIT:**

You can also use this

```
foreach (string printer in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
   //Add in combo box
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to immediately get the pop-up that new Printer Found/Disconnected... you must have to run some code in background continuously Windows Service is the best for that.. and using the below code you can get the installed printer so first store the currently installed printer in list and after each 10(or any you want) second get the installed printer again if difference found propmt the message accordingly..

this is the snippet to get the installed printer..

```
private string[] GetAvailablePrinters()
{
    var installedPrinters = new string[PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count];
    PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.CopyTo(installedPrinters, 0);

    var printers = new List<string>();
    var printServers = new List<string>();
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");

    foreach (var printer in searcher.Get())
    {
        var serverName = @"\\" + printer["SystemName"].ToString().TrimStart('\\');
        if (!printServers.Contains(serverName))
            printServers.Add(serverName);
    }

    foreach (var printServer in printServers)
    {
        var server = new PrintServer(printServer);
        try
        {
            var queues = server.GetPrintQueues();
            printers.AddRange(queues.Select(q => q.Name));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Handle exception correctly
        }
    }

    return printers.ToArray();
}
```

---

You might need to add the **System.Management, System.Drawing, System.Printing** references in you project..

Comment: This seems to list the printers with drivers on the system but if they have been unplugged does it still work?

Comment: @Eric Agree with your point.. right.. i may not reduce the count.. as driver are still installed.. let me try

Comment: hi sir uhmm im pretty much new to c# i dont know how to put this codes to the windows form. can you enlighten me please. this is very hard for me :(

Comment: i still dont have the idea on how to handle the exception correctly sir @DeepakSharma.

Comment: on button click event you just need to call the above defined method.. `GetAvailablePrinters` it will return the array of string representing the printer name..

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'ManagementObjectSearcher' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error 2 The type or namespace name 'PrintServer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

sir @DeepakSharma how can i handle this errors?

Comment: @Rozky did you read last line of my post?? I clearly said you need to add the reference of the three dll.. **System.Management, System.Drawing, System.Printing**