# How to print to a network printer in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking, printing

I'm trying to print out a set of strings to a network printer in C#.

I know the printer's **IP** and **MAC address** (Not installed to my PC)

The thing is that I am not able to detect this printer. Instead I get a collection of 4 **local** printers that are installed to my PC.

**NOTE:** There are 2 more network printers installed to my PC but I am not able to detect them either.

This is my code:

```
public string PageCreate( string printerName, string jsonString ) {
    string result = "1";
    if ( jsonString != null && jsonString.Length > 0 ) {
        JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse( jsonString );
        string userName = jsonObj["userName"].ToString();
        string userDept = jsonObj["userDept"].ToString();
        string userPhone = jsonObj["userPhone"].ToString();
        string date = jsonObj["date"].ToString();
        var items = jsonObj["items"];
        string total = jsonObj["total"].ToString();
        string comments = jsonObj["comments"].ToString();

        if ( items != null ) {                    
            try {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                // Some string added to sb

                // Here I get 4 local printers in 'printers' collection
                string query = "SELECT * from Win32_Printer";
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher( query );
                ManagementObjectCollection printers = searcher.Get();

                foreach ( ManagementObject printer in printers ) {
                    if ( !String.IsNullOrEmpty( printer.Properties["PortName"].Value.ToString() ) ) {
                        PropertyDataCollection props = printer.Properties;
                        string port = printer.Properties["PortName"].Value.ToString();                                
                    }
                }

                stringToPrint = new StringReader( sb.ToString() );
                printFont = new Font( "Arial", 10 );

                PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();

                //printerName = XX.X.X.XXX (IP address)
                doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;
                doc.DocumentName = "ESS_Order_" + userName + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm");
                doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler( this.PagePrint );
                if ( doc.PrinterSettings.IsValid ) {
                    doc.Print();
                }
            }
            catch {
                result = "0";
            }
            finally {
                stringToPrint.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**NOTE#2:** I do not want to popup printer dialog box

Comment: Is the printer installed on the machine?

Comment: No it's not. I just have the IP. Also, I can not get 2 network printers that are installed to my machine

Comment: for finding printers [how-to-get-the-list-of-all-printers-in-computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354435/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-printers-in-computer) should help, it only gets the installed printers but not sure how you would actually be able to print to a printer that is not installed