# How to print file in specific Printer?

Tags: c#

I want to print my file with a specific printer. However it always selects the same printer for the job. I'm using `Spire.Pdf;` for .NET. My code is as follows:

```
[...]
     PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
     pdf.LoadFromFile(path);
     pdf.PrintSettings.PrinterName = "HP";

     pdf.Print();
     pdf.Dispose();
[...]
```

I have two printers. One of them is named "EPSON L310 Series", the other one is the printer named "HP".
Even if I set `pdf.PrintSettings.PrinterName = "HP";` it selects the "EPSON L310 Series" for the printing job.

[image: My printers, the HP is selected by default in the dialog]

As you can see, "HP" is by default selected in the printing dialog.

Comment: Where is class `PdfDocument ` from? It can't be [this Microsoft class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.pdf.pdfdocument), since that doesn't have a `Print()` method.

Comment: it is "using Spire.Pdf;" @MatthewWatson

Comment: What happens if you put `pdf.PrintSettings.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();` before calling `pdf.Print()`?

Comment: Also have a look at [this sample](https://github.com/eiceblue/Spire.PDF-for-.NET/blob/master/CS/16_Print/TrayPrintFirstApproach.cs) which uses `PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters` to determine the available printers. You might want to dump that out to see what it thinks is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can not reliably control the output printer from a programm.

At best you can show the print dialog, where the user can override the output printer this time.

You can name as you did. It is even possible to get all Printers by name: [How to get the list of all printers in computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354435/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-printers-in-computer)
However at that point, you are basically re-inventing the print dialog.

Also note that technically those are not printers. Those are print *queues*. For such a simple case, it might not mater. But once you get into finer details like Multiple Printers per queue, it maters.