# Use of redirected printer with RDP on windows server with winforms application

Tags: c#, printing, server, rdp

I noticed that each time I login with RDP on a windows server, my redirected printer get a different name based on my RDP ID.

In my winforms app I need to print a pdf file directly to the redirected printer without user intervention for confirming.
As I understand, the assigning of the printer to use is based on it's name.
But while the name of the printer keeps changing, this doesn't seem to be the way to address this issue.

On a regular pc it just works fine, because you than have a fixed name for the network printer.
I'm looking for some advice on how to get a better solution for this.

Comment: Removed the sql-server-2008-r2 tag as it's not relevant to the question. BTW, SQL Server 2008 R2 is unsupported.

Comment: Install a network printer and use the printer instead of a local printer which is different on each server.

Comment: @jdweng I think that might not be possible. Some companies have a common RDP server where everybody can log in and the admins have configured it so that it always redirect to the physically nearest server. Like RDP servers are in Canada, office A is in Mexico, office B is in Italy. office A and office B should not have the same printer. And on top of that... I don't think the OP is in the possition to change anything about the way how the printer association works.

Comment: @Giancarlo - I am afraid you have to get all printers using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354435/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-printers-in-computer) and then filter the one with your RDP ID... And hopefully you know the RDP ID. Is it your user id? Or MachineName? The ID should be based on something.

Comment: @Legacy Code, thanks for the link.
The RDP ID is given "randomly" and not necesseraly starting from 1.
So I could try to go through the printers, but probably find a few same named printer, with only the ID being different.
For example "Star TSP100 Cutter (TSP143) (redirected 3)" means user with RDP ID #3 has this printer redirected from their PC
The next user can have "Star TSP100 Cutter (TSP143) (redirected 9)".
So filtering on "Star TSP100 Cutter (TSP143) (redirected" still gives multiple printers.
I've never understood why this mechanism works with a name and not a GUID or something

Comment: Is the RDP Id stored somewhere like environment variables?

Comment: With Windows the Printer has to be installed on a machine for a driver to be used for printing.  I do not think you want to write directly to the printer IP address,.  So you need a company policy to first get a printer(s) installed on the server.  Second you do not just want to use the printer name but also a location.

Comment: @jdweng Thats not what OP is trying to do. He is just trying to identify the printer in the RDP machine that is assigned to the logged in user. He is not trying to install a driver or write directly to any IP address... He just want to know how to identify (out of all redirected printers) which one the user's assigned printer. Nothing else. It's a problem, because he does not know the RDP ID.

Comment: The first step is to make sure a compatible printer is installed on each machine.  You cannot print without the driver installed.